# Как получить данные с магнитного датчика TLV493D-A1B6 по I2C на stm32?

Tags: c, микроконтроллеры, stm32

Необходимо получить данные с магнитного датчика **TLV493D-A1B6** по **I2C**. Датчик используется на плате **stm32-l010rb**.

Новичок в программировании контроллеров, поэтому хотелось бы знать, что вообще нужно делать? С чего начать?

Comment: На ответ не тянет, так - общее направление. 1) Разобраться с документацией на датчик - какие настройки I2C ему нужны, в каком виде он выдает данные, по запросу выдает или сам. 2) Разобраться с документацией на микроконтроллер - как обеспечить требуемые настройки I2C, как отправить (если надо) запрос, как получить пришедшие данные и как ,вообще, узнать, что они пришли. 3) Организовать (в соответствии с тем, в чем разбирались) взаимодействие МК и датчика. 4) Пересчитать полученные данные в удобный для работы вид. PS. Можно еще добавить фильтрацию, если сигнал грязный.

Comment: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=419380.0